# Checkbox in VBA giving run time error 424

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a check box in VBA but whenever I try to run the below macro I am getting the following error:

> Run time Error 424, Object Required.

This is the macro:

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()
   If CheckBox3.Value = False Then
      MsgBox "You unchecked the box"
   Else
      MsgBox "You checked the box"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to include more detail and have improved how your question is phrased. This should help to increase the number of people who see your question. If you have any more details about the error please update your question accordingly. You should also search this site for similar questions that may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+time+error+424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in which UserForm you are working, or just `Me` if the code is in the used UserForm.

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()
       If Me.CheckBox3.Value = False Then
          MsgBox "You unchecked the box"
       Else
          MsgBox "You checked the box"
       End If
End Sub
```

And with that code, you don't create a checkbox, you just use it.

Comment: If I use Me Keyword am getting 'Invalid use of Me keyword'.  Actually I'm creating one excel document which contains list of bluetooth devices. Now user has to select few bluetooth devices. Can you explain me in this context.

Comment: This code should be found in your UserForm's code as it is an "event listener" (click on checkbox). But to use the values of your check boxes in further code, you will need to replace `Me` by the name of your UserForm as it'll be better to place treatment code in a module. So you'll have to check the values of your checkboxes to know which one are selected